# Animation with power point

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have four points on the left side in power point 2007 as follow:

```
point 1
point 2 
point 3
point 4
```

I use the animation to show these points step by step by each  mouse click.

My Question is, how to show one different foto by each mous click on the right side?

Wehn point 1 is shown, i would like that foto 1 is shown in the same time, when point 2 is shown, i would like to hide foto 1 and show foto 2.. and so on

Comment: You can't use different slides and slide transitions?

Answer (score 1):

Give all items of the slide an appear animation.  so in you animation pane it will list, point 1, point 2, point 3 point 4, picture 1......

Then reposition the animations so they are order point 1, picture 1, point 2.....etc

Now right click on picture one animation line and select start with previous and the point and picture will start at the same time.

Comment: as for the disappear, use a disappear animation for the point and picture before the next one is due to appear

Answer (score 1):

Build the slide with the four points and the four pictures where you want them to appear even if the pictures are overlapping to start out with.  Select the **Animations** option. Start by selecting the second line and then how you want it to appear - **Appear**, **Blinds**, **Fly In** . Specify on click for the start.  Then select the picture you want displayed with the first item, and specify **Exit Effects** to have it disappear when you click and click on the picture you want to appear with the second item and again select the way you want it to appear.  Repeat this process for each of the lines and pictures, removing the prior picture when you add the new one.  This can give you a nice animation for your presentation.

You have to remember to have the **Exit Effects** for the pictures to remove or you will end up with the mess on the page.

I would then suggest making for separate slides that are normally hidden, that represent the four states, and use those slides when printing, or posting to a form where you can't show the animation.  This makes printing work, and gives you the visuals during the live presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Or, why not use four slides, with different LHS titles emphasised, and different images.

I have to use this approach anyway for some of my work (because animations do not translate well when the presentation is uploaded to a (for example Elluminate) webboard. Even when used natively I find filesize is not a problem and it runs just as fast as animation.